# Joomla! controller confusion. What does the require_once JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers/route.php'; do

Tags: php, joomla, controller, joomla2.5

I am new to Joomla! and I am studying component. The component is com_users. By default based on what I understand in reading the documentation. It will look for a file named 'users.php' and then initialize the controller.

BTW here's the hierarchy of files inside com_users.

```
com_users
 - controller
   - index.php
   - registration.php
 - helpers
   - route.php
 - models
   - registration.php
 - views
   - registration
     - tmpl
       - default.php
     - index.php
     - view.html.php
 - controller.php
 - index.php
 - metadata.xml
 - router.php
 - users.php
```

Here's the code inside users.php

```
require_once JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers/route.php';

// Launch the controller.
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Users');
$controller->execute(JRequest::getCmd('task', 'display'));
$controller->redirect();
```

** I am confused; what does require_once JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers/route.php'; really do? I am thinking that line supposed to include the file.

** Does the joomla! execute particular method by default inside that route.php?

** What does redirect do actually?

Please don't hate me if this is very novice :)

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component)?

Comment: How much PHP do you know? Do you know what require_once in PHP means nad have you tried to find out?

Comment: @ilias - yes i tried looking on that and I've read that before asking the question.

Comment: @Elin - I am not an expert in php and yes I also read php documentation about require_once

Comment: Usually `route.php` files have classes for the SEF appearance of links.

Comment: Then you know that require_once includes the file if it has not been included already. I'm not  sure what your question is.  Why would including the file cause anything to be executed?  `$controller->redirect()` executes the redirect method that is part of the `$controller` class. Basically it says where to go after the execution of the task. If you can get a copy of Joomla! Programming it does a great job reviewing the trace.